# Picture upload folder has too many files (10k limit), now I need to change the php-sql control panel

Tags: php, sql, upload, directory, limit

I have quite the predicament and I'm looking for the most efficient strategy of dealing with it:

I run a simple news site with basic articles which have images attached to them, similar to a blog. PHP-SQL frontend and administration panel.

The problem is that whoever made the original source did not consider that number of jpgs uploaded would exceed certain system limits, and now I can't upload in that folder anymore.

Each solution I think of requires a compromise, the worst one of which is obviously... manually editing over 10000 sql records.

...Now I need to transition to a folder with subfolder or to another folder on the same level, but how can I best do this while still maintaining functionality in the frontend and backened (i.e. avoiding 404 on the image files).

I was thinking of creating a *switch*  or an *if* statement that would assign fixed (by me) folders based on if the  ID of the sql record is larger or smaller than the top most value the latest one of from today (when I hit this wall), but if so, I have to learn to work around the PHPMAKER source (it's a nice table manager generator software).

I would love to implement some dynamic upload folder based on variables, but I don't know how. Here's a sample of the code which deals with the configuring the uploading:

adding a picture to row to the folder "picarticles" (the one):

```
    $this->picture->UploadPath = "/../picarticles/";
    if ($this->picture->Upload->Action == "1") { // Keep
        if ($rsold) {
            $rsnew['picture'] = $rsold->fields['picture'];
        }
    } elseif ($this->picture->Upload->Action == "2" || $this->picture->Upload->Action == "3") { // Update/Remove
    if (is_null($this->picture->Upload->Value)) {
        $rsnew['picture'] = NULL;
    } else {
        $rsnew['picture'] = ew_UploadFileNameEx(ew_UploadPathEx(TRUE, $this->picture->UploadPath), $this->picture->Upload->FileName);
    }
    $this->picture->ImageWidth = 500; // Resize width
    $this->picture->ImageHeight = 400; // Resize height
    }
```

or  in rendering the picture from a row:

```
        $this->picture->UploadPath = "/../picarticles/";
        if (!ew_Empty($this->picture->Upload->DbValue)) {
            $this->picture->ViewValue = $this->picture->Upload->DbValue;
            $this->picture->ImageWidth = 100;
            $this->picture->ImageHeight = 80;
            $this->picture->ImageAlt = $this->picture->FldAlt();
        } else {
            $this->picture->ViewValue = "";
        }
        $this->picture->ViewCustomAttributes = "";
```

this is for adding the timestamp, which would be an interesting candidate for the dynamic stuff:

```
        $this->timestamp->SetDbValueDef($rsnew, ew_CurrentDateTime(), NULL);
    $rsnew['timestamp'] = &$this->timestamp->DbValue;
```

or adding maybe I could use the first or second term out of a string of keywords to act as a folder, since that wouldn't create just as many new folders as there were new jpgs..

```
    $this->keywords->SetDbValueDef($rsnew, $this->keywords->CurrentValue, NULL, FALSE);
```

Comment: How about just use the date.. or month or whatever - 'pictures-12-12'

Comment: I'm... not well versed enough in PHP; I'm not used to dealing with variables in that form (full of ->and->...), so I'm not sure where to start hacking the code. Maybe someone here has a the most optimal strategy to take care of it, and on my own, I would need to experiment for some time to reach that result.

Comment: Looks like $this->picture->upload->filename is a good place to start.. date('Y-m-d') to get the formatted date. Use print_r( $var, true ) to dump out arrays of vars. This will help you untangle the nested arrays.